# Are there any known issues with using require to import dust.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, dust.js

Unlike the other libraries I am attempting to import via require.js, dust.js is returning "undefined." My file paths and everything are correct. This is the version of dust.js I am using:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linkedin/dustjs/master/dist/dust-full.js

Does anyone know what the deal could be?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

This version of dust does not support asynchronous module definition (AMD) and so needs to be wrapped in a requirejs define statement, thus:

```
define("dust", [], function () {
  . . . native dust code . . .
  return dust;
});
```